# React Native (EXPO) Google Sign in - build fails IOS

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

On EXPO, I am trying to use sign in with google with this package: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin

This is the depedency on package.json:

```
 "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.2.2
```

This is the CODE:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
  // Get the users ID token
  const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

  // Create a Google credential with the token
  const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

  // Sign-in the user with the credential
  return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
}
```

However, when building for iOS (eas build --profile preview --platform ios) I am getting this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn":
  In Podfile:
    EXGoogleSignIn (from `../node_modules/expo-google-sign-in/ios`) was resolved to 11.0.0, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0.2)
    ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn (from `../node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/ios`) was resolved to 7.2.2, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn
    RNGoogleSignin (from `../node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin`) was resolved to 7.2.2, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 6.1.0)
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by remove this dependency in ***package.json*** (Deprecated expo google sign in):

```
"expo-google-sign-in": "^11.0.0",
```